# Unexpected behavior in VBScript with SendKeys

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vbscript, plink

I'm attempting to create a VBScript I can run from a scheduled task to restart our SonicWall firewall.  The firewall is a "lower-end" business model (TZ400), and I periodically have to reboot it because our Internet connection seems to be bogged down (that's another issue that I'll have to research later).

I found the following code on another site for using `plink.exe` and modified it for my environment:

```
Set sw= CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sw.run"C:\plink\path\Plink.exe -ssh adminuser@X.X.X.X -pw adminpassword"
WScript.Sleep 500

sw.SendKeys "restart"
sw.SendKeys "{Enter}"
WScript.Sleep 800

sw.SendKeys "yes"
sw.SendKeys "{Enter}"
WScript.Sleep 10000

sw.SendKeys "exit"
sw.SendKeys "{Enter}"
```

Unfortunately, when I run this script, it seems to skip over some of the characters from the `SendKeys` method calls.  If I run it from my machine (Windows 7), I can usually get it to pass "enough" characters in order to complete the operation, but when I try running the same script on the server (Windows Server 2008 R2 - I've connected through RDP), it goes completely haywire.  See the screenshot below for an example after one particularly "wrong" attempt.

[image: plink session from VBScript]

I've tried putting a delay between each of the commands and it's corresponding `{ENTER}`, but that just seems to make it worse.  I've tried enclosing the text to send in parentheses just in case it had something to do with the syntax of the method call, but that didn't help either.

From what I can tell, it seems that the command prompt is simply not able to "keep up" with the `SendKeys` method for some reason.  Has anyone else experienced this issue, and does anyone have a suggestion for the best way to avoid or get around it?  For example, is there a way to "slow down" the execution of the script in some way?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

---

***EDIT:*** I've been able to get the script to execute successfully on the server by altering the script to send each character separately with a 100ms sleep between them:

```
Set sw= CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sw.run"C:\plink\path\Plink.exe -ssh adminuser@X.X.X.X -pw adminpassword"
WScript.Sleep 500

sw.SendKeys "r"
WScript.Sleep 100
sw.SendKeys "e"
WScript.Sleep 100
sw.SendKeys "s"
WScript.Sleep 100
sw.SendKeys "t"
WScript.Sleep 100
sw.SendKeys "a"
WScript.Sleep 100
sw.SendKeys "r"
WScript.Sleep 100
sw.SendKeys "t"
WScript.Sleep 100
sw.SendKeys "{Enter}"
WScript.Sleep 800

sw.SendKeys "y"
WScript.Sleep 100
sw.SendKeys "e"
WScript.Sleep 100
sw.SendKeys "s"
WScript.Sleep 100
sw.SendKeys "{Enter}"
WScript.Sleep 10000

sw.SendKeys "e"
WScript.Sleep 100
sw.SendKeys "x"
WScript.Sleep 100
sw.SendKeys "i"
WScript.Sleep 100
sw.SendKeys "t"
WScript.Sleep 100
sw.SendKeys "{Enter}"

wScript.quit
```

While this workaround seems to work, it seems a bit "brute-force" and doesn't actually resolve whatever the underlying issue is, so I'm still interested in any thoughts or suggestions.

***NOTE:*** While this does allow me to run the VBScript manually from the command line, I'm still having issues getting it to run from the Scheduled Task.  It seems to start and finish, but the firewall never actually restarts.  *Nevermind...* I know why it isn't running from the Scheduled Task, and I'm going to have to come up with a better script to handle this particular operation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but, as I stated in my question, I tried that without success. Also if you note the screenshot, the "missing" characters can be in the middle of the word (`restat` instead of `restart` - missing the last `r`, but not the final `t` character), which, unfortunately, wouldn't be solved by waiting after the command is sent.

Comment: Ah, I must have over looked that. . . I suppose doing a `sw.AppActivate "%WinTitle%"` where `%WinTitle%` is the actual value of the plink window title first after connection and before puttying in the sendkeys wouldn't help? If not, I wonder if the SSH session lags and using sendkeys just doesn't get send to the terminal or whatever when there is a lag.

Comment: I've not tried that, but I certainly can give it a shot when I get back to the office tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah no worries, I've written quite a few scripting using sendkey functions with batch and even some with PowerShell in case any help, here's a list: https://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a510662%20body%3a%20sendkeys feel free to browse and poke around in case any are helpful I suppose.

Comment: Check out this post in case it helps with the reboot problem at least: https://www.sonicwall.com/en-us/support/knowledge-base/170502775276425